# How to find the observation in each node of the MOB tree? (partykit package)

Tags: r, party

I have used the partykit package to create a Model-Based Partitioning (MOB) tree on a dataset and I wondered if there was a way to see which observations in our dataset pass that rules and fall in each node. (I want to have separate data frame for each node base on the tree rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `predict(..., type = "node")` for all `partykit` trees to obtain the predicted terminal node ID. And then you can use that for `split()`ting the data set. For example:

```
library("partykit")
tr <- lmtree(dist ~ speed, data = cars)
plot(tr)
```

[image: lmtree]

```
split(cars, predict(tr, type = "node"))
## $`3`
##    speed dist
## 1      4    2
## 2      4   10
## 3      7    4
## 4      7   22
## 5      8   16
## 6      9   10
## 7     10   18
## 8     10   26
## 9     10   34
## 10    11   17
## 11    11   28
## 12    12   14
## 13    12   20
## 14    12   24
## 15    12   28
## 
## $`4`
##    speed dist
## 16    13   26
## 17    13   34
## 18    13   34
## 19    13   46
## 20    14   26
## 21    14   36
## 22    14   60
## 23    14   80
## 24    15   20
## 25    15   26
## 26    15   54
## 27    16   32
## 28    16   40
## 29    17   32
## 30    17   40
## 31    17   50
## 
## $`5`
##    speed dist
## 32    18   42
## 33    18   56
## 34    18   76
## 35    18   84
## 36    19   36
## 37    19   46
## 38    19   68
## 39    20   32
## 40    20   48
## 41    20   52
## 42    20   56
## 43    20   64
## 44    22   66
## 45    23   54
## 46    24   70
## 47    24   92
## 48    24   93
## 49    24  120
## 50    25   85
```

Comment: Is there a way to get the sample size (n) of all nodes in the tree?

Comment: If you only want to get the sample size, then this is stored in the `info` of each node as `nobs`. Thus, you can do: `nodeapply(tr, nodeids(tr), function(x) info_node(x)$nobs)`. To obtain the full data associated with a particular node, use fro example: `data_party(tr, id = 2)`.

Comment: Much appreciated! Thanks